# Footer on bottom of screen, context should scroll underneath it

Tags: css, footer

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, but I can't seem te find the answer that suits my exact question.

I want a footer(-image) at the bottom of the *screen*, and it should stay at the bottom of the screen when scrolling down. This means the footer should me above the content.

I've tried this several times, but every time I used it the footer was at the bottom of the screen at the beginning, but when I started scrolling it stayed at the same distance relative to the top of the page (meaning it scrolls upwards on the screen).

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite easy using [`postion:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

```
<footer>I Stay Fixed!</footer>
```

`footer{`
    [`position:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)`/*Fixes the footer so it cannot scroll*/`
    [`bottom:0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)`/*Fixes the footer to the bottom of the content window*/`
    [`z-index:999;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)`/*Places the footer above all other elements with smaller z-index*/`
  `}`

For an example, see the coding below:

```css
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    }
.content{
    height:1000px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Content</div>
<footer>I Stay Fixed!</footer>
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/zo3kes17/)

Comment: I thought I already tried this, but this time it worked! Thanks a lot! I suppose I've made some stupid mistake last time.

Comment: @Jelle every one makes stupid mistakes every now and then. Glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

`postion:fixed` and `z-index: 10` (example value - to make sure footer will not get covered by other objects

Answer (score 2):

I guess your HTML is something like this:

```
<footer>
  <img src="footer_image.jpg" />
</footer>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
footer
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**position: fixed** allows me to give a position to the footer with respect to the browser viewport.
**bottom: 0** means the gap between the footer and the bottom of the browser viewport will be 0.
**z-index: 100** makes sure the footer is above any other content with a lesser `z-index`.